# unable to submit from after replacing a div innerHTML with a form through javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Working on e-commerce site , i want to replace the cart items view once user click on 'proceed to checkout'  the items list is replaced with form through innerHTML but now  the from wont submit what should i do ?

so first this is the cart view[image]
and after clicking the "proceed to checkout " it is replaced with checkout through simply innerHTML [image: this is checkout page]
Below shows how i submit the form

```
let orRapper =document.getElementsByClassName("orderWrapper")
if(orRapper){

    orRapper[0].style.display = 'none'
    
    let checkOutBtn = document.getElementById("checkout")
    
    checkOutBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    
    let getTable = document.getElementById("tb1")
    
    getTable.innerHTML = orRapper[0].innerHTML
    
    $(".orderWrapper")[0].remove()
    
    })
    }
```

the  table that contain button "proceed to checkout" and the check out from is on same page i have made the checkout from display hidden as page loads then after clicking the buttn "proceed to checkout" the cart table is repalced with checkout form but now it wont submit .

Comment: instead of slamming it in with innerHTML why not do removeChild and appendChild. the appendChild should legitimize the form and the functionality expected will be there.

Comment: @tstrand66  thanks , i did one simple thing i added onclick method and then called a function whcih then submits the form , its working  great         <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="myFunction()"  id="btnsubmit">  let myFunction = ()=>{

document.getElementById("myform").submit()

}